# Javascript: .split returns: 'not a function error'

Tags: javascript, string, split

I'm trying to make a program that recognises palindromes, I was doing this by flipping the number around and comparing it to itself however I've run into issues with the first part.

I have two problems firstly and most importantly if I remove the comments before .split it returns the error

> invert.toString.split is not a function

Looking around before I understand this usually occurs when people try to call .split on something that is not a string however as I don't have any code between where I turn the number into a string and splitting it I don't see where that could be happening.

The second is just a matter of being neat and tidy. I know its possible to get the .toString.split... and stuff onto the line where I read invert however whenever I try it seems to read incorrectly and the console.logs just return [Function: toString].

```
function is_palindrome(number){
    var invert = number
    console.log (invert) //This is only here for bug checking purposes.
    invert.toString//.split("").reverse.join
    console.log (invert)// This is also for bug checking
//    if (invert=number){ these are commented out until I can get invert to     work properly.
//       return true
//    }
return false
}
```

Thanks for your time, any help is appreciate.

Comment: `.toString().split("")`

Comment: `toString` is a function, so call it like one.

Comment: Urgh. Please tell me it wasn't that simple.

Comment: You guys are magicians. Thanks a lot. Should I delete this now or something? You know. To hide my shame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not calling `toString`, you're referencing the `toString` function itself, not the string that it returns. Since the function doesn't have a `split` method, you recieve an error.

Make sure you actually call the functions you're using:

```
invert.toString().split("")
```

Comment: For what its worth I also need them on reverse and join.